# openPrimaryTab() not opening more than one tab with a tabLabel - Console

Tags: visualforce, javascript, tab, console, sforce

I am unable to open multiple tabs with a `tabLabel` but CAN open multiple tabs without a `tabLabel`. I can't find any documentation on why this would be happening or any further explanations on the `(optional)tabLabel:String` section of the `openPrimaryTab()` function. Any insight would be appreciated.

I have tried binding in a value, hard typing in a value, putting in a datetime and as far as I can tell, if there is any value in the tabLabel, then multiple tabs will not pop.

```
    sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null, '/' + id, true, 
   '{!title}', openSuccess, 'Case On Case');
```

When I remove the tabLabel, I am able to get multiple tabs to pop.

```
sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null, '/' + id, true, openSuccess, 'Case On Case');
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you need to specify `undefined` rather than defined as `null` in the first argument of

```
sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(***id:String***, url:URL, active:Boolean, (optional)tabLabel:String, (optional)callback:Function, (optional)name)
```

So, it will be as follows:

```
sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(undefined,"/"+id, true, '{!title}');
```

In the below picture you can see that clicking each record, it is opening in separate Primary tab with title.

[image: Open Primary Tab]

**Updating answer based on comments**

> If the ID corresponds to an existing primary tab, the existing tab is redirected to the given URL because the Salesforce console prevents duplicate tabs.

Now, if you do not specify the Id then it should be `undefined` as there is difference between `null` and `undefined`

Comment: Interesting.  What is the purpose of the ***ID:String***? Something I also discovered is that the callback function throws the function off as well. This works:   `sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(undefined,"/"+id, true, '{!title}',  'Case On Tab');`
this does not work `sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(undefined, '/' + id, true, '{!title}', openSuccess, 'Case On Tab');` I should note that my callback function was just an alert with no other logic.

Comment: it has difference, updating answer at bottom

Comment: Thank you for the update, that makes sense.  I am now confused on why it would work with a `NULL id` and no `tabLabel`. How does the `tabLabel` effect the `ID`?

Comment: tabLabel is specified in the code, Id shouldn't be null

Answer (score 1):

Had faced the same behaviour in past with [sforce.console.openPrimaryTab](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_openprimarytab.htm).

My conclusion is that it was a feature not a bug; as `tabLabel` is unique identifier of the tab or subTab, it behaves same as window name in [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).

Unfortunately its not documented anywhere.

Comment: what did you end up doing? Do you think it's worth opening up a case with Salesforce? I feel like there has to be a way to open multiple tabs with a tabLabel.

Comment: @SantanuBoral awesome, I will wait for your reply!